# Incompatibility of MinIO with Laravel version 9

Tags: laravel, minio

I have a laravel version 9 project and I want to use MinIO driver.
Currently I have to use

```
$composer require coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio
```

to install the MinIO driver in laravel. But this command would generate an error:

```
Problem 1
    - coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.13] require league/flysystem ~1.0 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.10] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.12).
    - coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio[1.0.15, ..., 1.0.16] require league/flysystem ^1.0.40 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.40, ..., 1.1.10] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.12).
    - Root composer.json requires coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio ^1.0 -> satisfiable by coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.16].
```

I checked that for Laravel version 9 the minimum version of league/flysystem is `3.8.0` while the league/flysystem that is listed in the coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio requirement is version `1.0.40`. Any Ideas how I should fix the problem and use MinIO driver with Laravel version 9?

Comment: it doesn't look like this package has had any updates for the past 6 years. It would be better for you to try a different package. There are PR to solve this issue, So you might be able to fork it yourself and use that too.

Comment: @AnujShrestha Thanks, you're right. I am trying to submit the forked version (mine) in Packagist. But it keeps telling me `A package with the name coraxster/flysystem-aws-s3-v3-minio already exists.` and `The vendor name "coraxster" was already claimed by someone else on Packagist.org. You may ask them to add your package and give you maintainership access.` Do you know how I can submit my forked version? I have already changed the name of repo but still no luck.

Comment: You don't need to submit the fork to packagist. You just use that fork on your project. If you really want to submit it then you will have to create it as a separate package and submit it.